# Find the next 3 items in the sequence

Tags: pattern

A sequence goes as follows:

```
A
AA
BA
ABAA
AAABBA
CABBAA
ACAABBBA
AAACBACBAA
CAACABAAACABBA
...
```

It's an altered version of a sequence you all know! The answer should be in the above format.

Additionally, will D ever appear?

Comment: It is very similar to: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2471/a-sequence-named-by-a-childrens-toy/2473

Comment: And @ThePopMachine said why D will never appear, because "2222" will never occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, etc...

ACBAACAAABCAACAABBAA
AAACABBAACCAABACBAACBABBBA
CAACAABBBABCBAABAAACABBAACABAACBAA

It's the same kind of sequence where the next item describes the item above it in [quantity of number][number] format.

EDIT: The requested number format.

13211311123113112211
11131221133112132113212221
3113112221232112111312211312113211

Comment: +1 if you post it all in number format

Comment: I added a bonus too

Comment: You need to include the original sequence for the +1

Comment: He obviously knows the sequence…what is this vote bargaining about?

Comment: Okay okay, fine.