# Is this sequence new?

Tags: pattern, word-sequence

I can't help but wonder *if we've seen it before*. I do know however it seems to be entirely made from booleans! I can't remember any booleans?!?!?!

> true
>   true false true true
>   true false true false true
>   true false false true false true true true false true true
>   true true false true true false false true false false true true true false true false true
>   true false false true true false false false false true true true false false true false false true true

I'm almost positive this is a *known pattern*, but maybe I'm wrong? Do any of you know the pattern, and can you confirm *if it's been here before*?

Comment: And none of that's meta. Everything in the puzzle is important.

Comment: @Deusovi I would call it a duplicate, but I would vote to close the other one, as I think this is the better one.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: I was under the impression that duplicate status was always resolved in favor of the earlier one.

Comment: @Deusovi, I thought I remembered a meta discussion on that, where the suggestion was that the *better* question should be kept (what if someone posts a two-liner with no formatting and spelling mistakes, and someone else later posts a puzzle with a similar premise, but weaves it into an excellent story and obviously puts a lot of work into it?), but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @Deusovi I've posted a [new meta question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/what-to-do-when-a-duplicate-is-better-than-the-original).

Comment: @Deusovi This is not a *duplicate* it's a **variation**. If you call this a duplicate you may as well close almost all Monty Hall related problems, and Knights and Knaves, etc.

Comment: @warspyking: No, it's a duplicate except slightly encoded. I would also vote to close the Monty Hall problem even if it was rot13d and presented as a "break the code and THEN answer" question.

Comment: @Deusovi The "original" asks for the next 3 numbers. This questions asks for you to figure out the puzzle itself, and then determine if it's a known puzzle on Puzzling.SE. Sounds like a variation!

Comment: @warspyking Not different enough to not be considered a duplicate, in my opinion.

Comment: @Deusovi I think your mind wandered, did you mean variation?

Comment: @warspyking: No, I meant duplicate. Note the double negative - the phrasing was probably a bit too unclear.

Comment: @Deusovi Oh my gosh I see it now. I can't believe I didn't notice that haha

Comment: I think you should also all note that the other puzzle was posed by ***the same person***. It's even a meta-duplicate!

Comment: @Ian MacDonald Lol, it's not a duplicate! It's a variation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we convert the sequence to binary, with true=1 and false=0...

> 1
>  1011
>  10101
>  10010111011
>  11011001001110101
>  1001100001110010011

Then we convert from binary to decimal...

> 1
>  11
>  21
>  1211
>  111221
>  312211

We see that the sequence is

> The age old sequence where each number describes the count of digits in the previous number, so the value after 1 is "one one", or 11.

Has it been here before?

> [Yeah, it has.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/find-the-next-3-items-in-the-sequence?rq=1) This isn't the original form, but it's another warspyking classic, which is really just as good.

Comment: *but it's another warspyking classic, which is really just as good.* Made me smile